# c function for checking if value is present in linked list

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I have two linked lists with rows, columns and values, for which im trying to write a function which checks for an entry if it is present in the next row aswell. 
So e.g. given row5 col2, check if row6 is present and then if col2 is present in row6. Somehow the function isn't running and I hope someone can help me with this. If you need more code or explanation, just hit me up.

**thanks** in advance

David

```
 /*
    row: 1 
    column: 3 value: 0 
    column: 7 value: 0 
    row: 5 
    column: 2 value: 0 
    column: 6 value: 0 
    row: 6 
    column: 2 value: 0 
    */

        // Row list
        struct row_list
        {
            int row_number;
            struct row_list *link_down;
            struct value_list *link_right;
        };

        // Column list + value
        struct value_list
        {
            int column_index;
            int value;
            struct value_list *next;
        };

// col list
void create_value_node(unsigned int data, unsigned int j, struct row_list **z)
{
    struct value_list *temp, *d;

    temp = (struct value_list*)malloc(sizeof(struct value_list));
    temp->column_index = j;
    temp->value = data;
    temp->next = NULL;

    if ((*z)->link_right==NULL)
        (*z)->link_right = temp;
    else
    {
        d = (*z)->link_right;
        while(d->next != NULL)
            d = d->next;
        d->next = temp;
    }
}

// row list
void create_row_list(struct row_list **start, unsigned int row, unsigned int column, struct array *p)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        struct row_list *z, *r;

        unsigned int rx = p[i].x;

        z = (struct row_list*)malloc(sizeof(struct row_list));
        z->row_number = rx;
        z->link_down = NULL;
        z->link_right = NULL;
        if (i==0)
            *start = z;
        else
        {
            r = *start;
            while (r->link_down != NULL)
                r = r->link_down;
            r->link_down = z;
        }

        while(p[i].x==rx)
        {

                create_value_node(0, p[i].y, &z);
                i++;
        }
        i--;
    }
}

        bool function(struct row_list *start,int x, int y){
            struct row_list *tmpr;
            struct value_list *tmpc;
            tmpr=start;
            int currow = x;


                while((tmpr->row_number)<currow){
                    tmpr=tmpr->link_down;
                }


            if (tmpr->link_right != NULL)
            { tmpc = tmpr->link_right;}

            int curcol = y;

            tmpr=tmpr->link_down;

            if((tmpr->row_number)==(currow+1)){
                while (tmpc != NULL) {
                    if((tmpc->column_index)==curcol) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    if((tmpc->column_index)>curcol) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    tmpc=tmpc->next;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

    int main(){
    if(function(start,x,y)){
    printf("*%u*%u*%u***\n\n",x,y,v);
      }
```

Comment: Can you please be more specfic than "Somehow the function isn't running". More detailed information about your problem would make it much easier to help you. Have you tried debugging the code?

Comment: Can you show How are you calling void create_value_node and how are you declaring struct array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three bugs in `function`

In this code:

```
            while((tmpr->row_number)<currow){
                tmpr=tmpr->link_down;
            }
```

you don't check for `tmpr` being NULL so you may end up dereferencing a NULL pointer. Instead try:

```
            while((tmpr->row_number)<currow){
                tmpr=tmpr->link_down;
                if (tmpr == NULL) return false;
            }
```

In this code:

```
        if (tmpr->link_right != NULL)
        { tmpc = tmpr->link_right;}
```

you only initialize `tmpc` when `link_right` isn't NULL. So later on, i.e. here

```
        while (tmpc != NULL) {
```

you may use an uninitialized `tmpc`

A simple fix for this is to always do the assignment

```
         tmpc = tmpr->link_right;
```

regardless of the value of `link_right`

In this code:

```
tmpr=tmpr->link_down;
```

you change `tmpr` but you never check for NULL. So here:

```
        if((tmpr->row_number)==(currow+1)){
```

you may be dereferencing a NULL pointer.

So add this extra check:

```
tmpr=tmpr->link_down;
if (tmpr == NULL) return false;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was able to fix the function due to your precise comments!